# Azure Functions - Logging Consolidation - Controlling the host log?

Tags: azure, logging, azure-functions

I run a system on top of a bunch of Azure Functions and I'm just tidying some last threads up. I mostly abandoned the logging provided out of the box by Azure functions because I found the flush timings to be super irregular and I also wanted to consolidate the logs from all of my functions into one spot and be able to query them. This all works for the most part but I have one annoying use-case remaining where if a function binding is faulty (e.g. the azure function method signature is wrong because someone checked garbage into Git) the function won't be invoked and even the log for the function wont be invoked but the error will instead be placed into a different file (the host log).

Now I guess I can just access the storage account that backs up the azure function and pull the host log from there but I was wondering if there was a better means of directly controlling/intercepting the logging in Azure Functions. Does anyone know if there is at least a way of getting it to flush more quickly?

Answer (score 1):

You can see host logs as well as function logs in associated Application Insights:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitoring#other-categories